# Create directory from windows explorer

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, osmand

I have my phone connected to my PC using USB cable. No I can see my phone's files. I would like to create folder named `tracks` in directory  `This PC\My Name\Card\Android\data\net.osmand.plus\files\osmand`, but after creating new folder procedure my explorer starts not responding and I need to reconnect cable. What might be wrong?

Comment: Could you please give a few more details: USB cable is clear, but what [connection mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/usb-connection-mode/info)? And what OS is running on your PC? Reading between the lines, am I correct you're using Windows (version?) and the built-in Explorer? Is there anything "popping up" on your Android device screen when that happens – and if so, what? What device is it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem generally occurs in MTP mode. Well, the workaround is to create a folder, [New Folder] (don't rename it). Just save the folder as it is. Then, rename it. I did it several times and it helps.